# For a not empty set $A$ let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ be the power set of $A$. Show that $A$ is not equivalent to $\mathcal{P}(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For a not empty set $A$ let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ be the power set of $A$. Show that $A$ is not equivalent to $\mathcal{P}(A)$

Well I´m trying to show it by contradiccion. So suppouse that $\sigma :A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$ is surjetive.So then I just need to find a subset $B=\{x: x \in A  \quad \textrm{and} \quad x \notin \mathcal{P}\}$.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem

Comment: I suspect you're conflating the terms "equivalent" (belonging to the same equivalence class of some equivalence relation) and "equipotent" (the existence of a bijective correspondence between the sets)

Comment: Try the set $B=\{x\in A\mid x\notin \sigma(x)\}$. Can you find an element $y$ in $A$ such that $\sigma(y)=B$?

Comment: $\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{P}$ but $\mathcal{A} \notin \mathcal{A}$